# Relabelling column from `RangeIndex` in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataset

```
    0           1           2
0   1.000000    0.063373    0.753792
1   0.063373    1.000000    0.031112
2   0.753792    0.031112    1.000000
```

When I do `similarity_df.columns` the answer is `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)` what I want is `Index(['0', '1', '2'], dtype='object')` and what I did is

`df.columns = ['0', '1', '2']`

The actual data is more than 2000 columns, and I need to select several column, how to make the code efficiently

Comment: I think it is dupe, `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: if you want to change column name you can do that by
 
`df.rename(columns={0:"Column0", 1:"Column1",2:"Column2",3:"Column2"})
df.head()
`
By assigning each column proper name will help you in your analysis.
Now as you mention that you have 2000 columns so you can have loop to name all your columns . This will make your analysis easy when dealing with a lot of columns   
Now if you want to change its type to str so you can do that by

 
`column0=df['column0'].astype(str)`